# UISearchBar - internal UITextField height issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm working on an app where I place a `UISearchBar` at the top of a `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableViewController`. The `UISearchBar` filters the contents of the `UITableView`.

I've left things alone so far (aside from customizing the colors to match my app's theme, which was hard enough!), but on anything except iPhone 4/5, the `UISearchBar` is dramatically too small.

Therefore, I'm trying to update the size of the font and the height of the internal `UITextField`.

All of this has proved remarkably difficult to accomplish, requiring quite a bit of customization. So, if you know of a library that makes this easier, please let me know in the comments.

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
// In a category for UISearchBar
- (void)setup {
    self.tintColor              = [UIColor offWhite];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        [self configureView:view];
    }
}
- (void)configureView:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        CGFloat fontSize, frameHeight;
        if (IS_IPHONE_4) {
            fontSize            = 14.0f;
            frameHeight         = 24.0f;
        } else if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            fontSize            = 14.0f;
            frameHeight         = 24.0f;
        } else if (IS_IPHONE_6) {
            fontSize            = 17.0f;
            frameHeight         = 28.0f;
        } else if (IS_IPHONE_6PLUS) {
            fontSize            = 20.0f;
            frameHeight         = 32.0f;
        } else {
            // iPad
            fontSize            = 24.0f;
            frameHeight         = 36.0f;
        }
        UITextField *textfield  = (UITextField *)view;
        textfield.font          = [UIFont buttonFontOfSize:fontSize];
        textfield.textColor     = [UIColor offWhite];
        textfield.tintColor     = [UIColor offWhite];
        CGRect frame            = textfield.frame;
        frame.origin.y          = (self.frame.size.height - frameHeight) / 2.0f;
        frame.size.height       = frameHeight;
        textfield.frame         = frame;
    }
    if (view.subviews.count > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
            [self configureView:subview];
        }
    }
}
```

> ***Note:*** I structured my code this way in case Apple changes the internal structure of the `UISearchBar`. I didn't want to hard-code index values.

So, this code "works", in that the end result is what I desire, namely, a taller `UISearchBar` with text sized as specified and the internal `UITextField` also taller, as specified. What I **don't** understand is the process of getting there.

1. If I call `[self.searchBar setup]` in my general AutoLayout process, it doesn't work (the internal `UITextField` is the wrong height). This makes sense to me, since the frame is `(0,0,0,0)` until the view is actually laid out.
2. If I call `[self.searchBar setup]` in my `-viewWillAppear:` method, it doesn't work (the internal `UITextField` is the wrong height). This **doesn't** make sense to me, since debugging shows the frames to still be `(0,0,0,0)`, but I thought `-viewWillAppear:` was called when everything was laid out and set up.
3. If I call `[self.searchBar setup]` in my `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, it "works", but the internal `UITextField` starts out the "normal" height and then "jumps" to the correct height some time after the view actually appears.

I set up the entire `UIViewController` in code, using pure AutoLayout. I simply cannot get the `UISearchBar` set up the way I want **BEFORE** the view finished loading and is displayed on screen. I've seen some funky stuff in the past, but I've always been able to force a view to render as desired. Is there something special behind the scenes with `UISearchBar`? Does anybody know how to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing auto-layout and manual layout (`someView.frame = …`) on the same view. You can't do that.

Instead, to change the height, set the `constant` on your view's height constraint to `frameHeight`. Let the auto-layout engine set the frame for you.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I know what you're saying, but I'm only doing the "outside" view with AutoLayout. And, anyway, it "works", like I said, it just gets there after the view is displayed, but the overall height of the `UISearchBar` is correct the whole time.